# How to Open Any Website in Android Application in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, web, android-applicationinfo

I just started a new appliction using android studio .. but i need to open a web page in my application i tried using web view but it doesnt worked out... when i open my app it crashes down

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and i included in java class file

```
private  WebView wb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings=wb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_references);
}
```

In manifest xml file i included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

but still my app crashes pllzz help me

## android #android-studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call super method and setcontentview first. Only after setContentView you can access to the functions `findViewByid` and all

> From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int))
>
> `setContentView(int resLayout)`: Set the activity content from a layout resource. The
>   resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

So if it isn't called no views will be added to your activity. Then you cant access any views at all.

Change it like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_references);


   wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings=wb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");
}
```

Comment: Good job! I just wanted to make a comment, please post stacktrace ;) Because I'm to lazy to read the full code.

Comment: @ReneM. Yeah.. Me too wanted to post this answer as comment, but it will be too long, so just decided to post it as an answer. :)